JavaFx sorting visualiser
I'm working on a sorting visualiser project in JavaFX. I have managed to get a bubble sort and insertion sort working however I am having issues with implementing the quicksort.
the code below is my quick sort implementation. The logic works when removing the visual side.
    private void quickSort(int[] arr, int high) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            enableButton(true);
            quickSortHelper(arr, 0, high);
        }).start();
    }

    private void quickSortHelper(int[] arr, int low, int high) {
        if (low < high) {
            int pi = partition(arr, low, high);
            quickSortHelper(arr, low, pi - 1);
            quickSortHelper(arr, pi + 1, high);
        }
    }

    private void qSwapHelper(int[] arr, int i, int j) {
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            swapBarsWithAnimation((Rectangle) mainAPane.getChildren().get(i), (Rectangle) mainAPane.getChildren().get(j), latch);
        });

        try {
            latch.await();
        } catch (Exception _) {
        }

        int temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
    }

    private int partition(int[] arr, int low, int high) {
        // choose the pivot
        int pivot = arr[high];

        int i = low-1;

        for (int j = low; j < high; j++) {
            if (arr[j] < pivot) {
                i++;
                qSwapHelper(arr, i, j);
            }
        }
        qSwapHelper(arr, i+1, high);
        return (i+1);
    }

below is how I manage the animations. I'm using 2 translation transitions which run simultaneously with a parallel transition. On completion, the anchors are updated in the anchor pane and the bars are removed before being readded in their swapped positions to reflect the visual state logically.
    private void swapBarsWithAnimation(Rectangle bar1, Rectangle bar2, CountDownLatch latch) {
        double bar1Pos = AnchorPane.getLeftAnchor(bar1);
        double bar2Pos = AnchorPane.getLeftAnchor(bar2);

        TranslateTransition bar1ToBar2Transition = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(DURATION_TIME), bar1);
        bar1ToBar2Transition.setByX(bar2Pos - bar1Pos);

        TranslateTransition bar2ToBar1Transition = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(DURATION_TIME), bar2);
        bar2ToBar1Transition.setByX(bar1Pos - bar2Pos);

        ParallelTransition pt = new ParallelTransition(bar1ToBar2Transition, bar2ToBar1Transition);

        Double finalBar2Pos = bar2Pos;
        Double finalBar1Pos = bar1Pos;
        pt.setOnFinished(_ -> {
            AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(bar1, finalBar2Pos);
            AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(bar2, finalBar1Pos);

            ObservableList<Node> children = mainAPane.getChildren();

            int indexOfBar1 = children.indexOf(bar1);
            int indexOfBar2 = children.indexOf(bar2);

            children.removeAll(bar1, bar2);
            children.add(indexOfBar1, bar2);
            children.add(indexOfBar2, bar1);

            bar1.setTranslateX(0);
            bar2.setTranslateX(0);

            latch.countDown();
        });

        pt.play();
    }

my understanding is that anything visual needs to run on the JavaFX main thread so I've used Platform.RunLater() to achieve this. As mentioned before my bubble sort and insertion are working great so it must be something to do with the use of recursion maybe?
I was thinking add the transitions to a queue or list then executing them, this way they would definitely run in order?
I am intending to add more sorts including merge sort and I assume I'll have to same issue.
Any help is greatly appreciated I'm a bit stuck.

You should use Task for the sort and use its progress tracking tools. https://www.pragmaticcoding.ca/javafx/elements/task-progress

What are the actual issues?

@DaveB thanks I'll look into it and see if I can implement anything

@James_D "duplicate children error" which is because the same node trying to be added. But I don't get that error with the other sorts

I think you should use a Task to find every state of the search. Store each change in a 2D list. Once the Task finishes, Use a Timeline to iterate through the 2D List at one-second intervals to show every step of the search.

This approach should be viable, though. The "duplicate children error" is at one of the children.add(...) lines in the onFinished handler? Are the animations running one at a time (it looks like they must be because of waiting for the latch)?

update I have no idea why this works but I wrapped 'adding the children back in' in a try catch and even though it produces exceptions the program runs and visually it looks how it should. Definitely a terrible solution but it works I guess. I need to figure out a more robust solution but for now it'll do

Is it guaranteed that i < j when you perform the swap? If not, the bars can be added in the wrong location in the child list, which will mess things up.

@James_D yes the animation runs and on complete the latch countdown before continuing with the loop

from debugging, i've noticed the index of bar 1 and 2 is often the same in the quick sort whereas it isn't in the others. still not sure why

"from debugging, i've noticed the index of bar 1 and 2 is often the same" That's where the problem is coming from (and indicates your implementation of the algorithm is incorrect; it is nothing to do with the visualization). If the two bars are the same bar, the removeAll(...) will remove just the one bar, and then the two calls to children.add(...) will attempt to add the bar twice, giving the error. The issue isn't apparent without the visualization, because swapping an element with itself is just a no-op, but it is being inefficient.

@James_D thank you I understand what problem I'm trying to fix now. I'm going to debug and figure out why they are the same

solution I added a simple check to see if I is different to J before attempting to swap. This is so simple and I've definitely overcomplicated the issue ahahah but I've learnt something though that's the main thing. Thanks for the help

Probably a more robust approach is to create a new list of the rectangles (List<Node> bars = new ArrayList<>(children);), then swap the bars in the new list in the usual way (Node temp = bars.get(indexOfBar1); bars.set(indexOfBar1, bars.get(indexOfBar2)); bars.set(indexOfBar2, temp);) and then copy the list back to the child list (children.set(bars);). This will work if i==j and if i > j (the latter still doesn't work correctly in your new implementation, though the implementation may guarantee this can't happen).

From the comments:

from debugging, i've noticed the index of bar 1 and 2 is often the same in the quick sort

This will cause an "duplicate child error". If the indexes are the same, then the two references to the bars refer to the same node: i.e. bar1 == bar2. Then
children.removeAll(bar1, bar2);

will just remove the one (and only) bar,
children.add(indexOfBar1, bar2);

will add the bar back in, and
children.add(indexOfBar2, bar1);

will attempt to add it a second time, throwing the exception.
Note also that if i > j, this will fail in a different way, as children.add(indexOfBar1, bar2); will add bar2 at the wrong location in the list.
It feels as though the situation where i >= j should never arise, but Quick Sort is a pretty complicated algorithm, and it's possible that, at least, i == j may be a valid scenario in some implementations of the partition*.
A more robust way to swap the bars is to create a temporary list, swap them in the temporary list, then copy the temporary list back to the child list:
    pt.setOnFinished(_ -> {
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(bar1, finalBar2Pos);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(bar2, finalBar1Pos);

        ObservableList<Node> children = mainAPane.getChildren();

        int indexOfBar1 = children.indexOf(bar1);
        int indexOfBar2 = children.indexOf(bar2);

        //children.removeAll(bar1, bar2);
        //children.add(indexOfBar1, bar2);
        //children.add(indexOfBar2, bar1);

        List<Node> bars = new ArrayList<>(children);
        Node temp = bars.get(indexOfBar1);
        bars.set(indexOfBar1, bars.get(indexOfBar2));
        bars.set(indexOfBar2, temp);
        children.setAll(bars);

        bar1.setTranslateX(0);
        bar2.setTranslateX(0);

        latch.countDown();
    });

* If I may be allowed an anecdote, my father's first ever job was to write an Algol compiler, and his boss was Tony Hoare. This was around the time that Hoare had just invented Quick Sort. My dad said that he and his colleagues spent a lot of time trying to understand how and why Quick Sort worked, but none of them could ever really explain why it was so efficient in the majority of cases. They speculated that Tony Hoare never really understood his own algorithm either (though I doubt this is the case).

Since this is just a bunch of Nodes in a Pane (the use of AnchorPane doesn't add much at all), there's no need to worry about the order of the Nodes in the container.  So, therefore, no need to remove and replace the Nodes either.
It's possible to set the location of each Node using layoutX and then use translateX to control the animation of the Nodes.  All of the logic can be divorced from the layout by using a list of Models that have Properties that  are bound to the Properties of the Nodes in the layout.  Like this:
class ElementModel(initialValue: Int, initialPosition: Int) {
    val number = SimpleIntegerProperty(initialValue)
    val position: IntegerProperty = SimpleIntegerProperty(initialPosition)
    val offset: DoubleProperty = SimpleDoubleProperty(0.0)
    val dip: DoubleProperty = SimpleDoubleProperty(0.0)
}

This is Kotlin.  The JavaFX ideas remain the same, however.
The layout then looks like this:
private fun createContent(): Region = BorderPane().apply {
        padding = Insets(20.0)
        center = mainAPane
        bottom = Button("Start").apply {
            setOnAction {
                isDisable = true
                quickSort(array) { this.isDisable = false }
            }
        }
        val startColour = Color.YELLOW
        array.forEachIndexed { index, i ->
            val element = ElementModel(i, index)
            elements.add(element)
            mainAPane.children += Label().apply {
                textProperty().bind(element.number.asString())
                prefWidth = labelWidth - 2.0
                styleClass += "element-label"
                background =
                    Background(BackgroundFill(startColour.interpolate(Color.DARKTURQUOISE, index / 20.0), null, null))
                layoutXProperty().bind(element.position.multiply(labelWidth))
                translateXProperty().bind(element.offset)
                translateYProperty().bind(element.dip)
                viewOrderProperty().bind(element.offset.map { it -> if (it != 0.0) 0.0 else 1.0 })
            }
        }
    }

The Nodes in this case are Labels, not Rectangles because it's just easier to deal with them.  Each label has a solid background colour that from a range between Color.YELLOW and Color.DARKTURQUOISE from left to right initially.
Each Label has its layoutX bound to it's position value times the Node width value, which is 25.  Additionally it has translateX Property bound to the offset value of the ElementModel and its translateY Property bound to the dip Property in the Model.  Both of these are 0 unless a transition is in progress.
Finally, the Nodes in tranisition need to be on the top of the SceneGraph (otherwise they move behind some of the other Nodes), so the viewOrderProperty() is bound such that it is 0.0 when translated, and 1.0 when not.
When testing, it was found that the algorithm often submits identical indexes for swapping, which made the visualization look like it had paused.  Rather than filtering those out, a "dip" animation was added where the element translated its "Y" component down and then back up:
    private fun animateElements(i: Int, j: Int, latch: CountDownLatch) {
        if (i == j) dipElement(i, latch) else swapVisualElements(i, j, latch)
    }

    private fun swapVisualElements(i: Int, j: Int, latch: CountDownLatch) {
        val elementI = elements.first { it.position.value == i }
        val elementJ = elements.first { it.position.value == j }
        val transition = object : Transition() {
            init {
                cycleDuration = Duration.millis(abs(i - j).coerceAtMost(8) * 140.0)
                setOnFinished {
                    elementI.offset.value = 0.0
                    elementJ.offset.value = 0.0
                    elementI.position.value = j
                    elementJ.position.value = i
                    latch.countDown()
                }
            }

            override fun interpolate(frac: Double) {
                elementI.offset.value =
                    ((elementJ.position.value * labelWidth) - (elementI.position.value * labelWidth)) * frac
                elementJ.offset.value =
                    ((elementI.position.value * labelWidth) - (elementJ.position.value * labelWidth)) * frac
            }
        }
        transition.play()
    }

    private fun dipElement(i: Int, latch: CountDownLatch) {
        val elementI = elements.first { it.position.value == i }
        val transition = object : Transition() {
            init {
                cycleDuration = Duration.millis(250.0)
                isAutoReverse = true
                cycleCount = 2
                setOnFinished {
                    elementI.dip.value = 0.0
                    latch.countDown()
                }
            }

            override fun interpolate(frac: Double) {
                elementI.dip.value = 20.0 * frac
            }
        }
        transition.play()
    }

In testing, it was found that a fixed cycle duration meant that the swaps of Nodes close together went painfully slowly, so the duration was set to grow as the Nodes were further apart - up to a point.
Then the actual quicksort subroutines were left basically untouched from the OP source code (except for the conversion to Kotlin):
    private fun quickSort(arr: IntArray, whenDone: () -> Unit) {
        val task: Task<Void> = object : Task<Void>() {
            override fun call(): Void? {
                quickSortHelper(arr, 0, arr.size - 1)
                return null
            }
        }
        task.setOnSucceeded { whenDone.invoke() }
        Thread(task).apply { isDaemon = true }.start()
    }

    private fun quickSortHelper(arr: IntArray, low: Int, high: Int) {
        if (low < high) {
            val pi = partition(arr, low, high)
            quickSortHelper(arr, low, pi - 1)
            quickSortHelper(arr, pi + 1, high)
        }
    }

    private fun qSwapHelper(arr: IntArray, i: Int, j: Int) {
        val latch = CountDownLatch(1)
        Platform.runLater { animateElements(i, j, latch) }
        try {
            latch.await()
        } catch (`_`: Exception) {
        }

        val temp = arr[i]
        arr[i] = arr[j]
        arr[j] = temp
    }

    private fun partition(arr: IntArray, low: Int, high: Int): Int {
        val pivot = arr[high]

        var i = low - 1

        for (j in low until high) {
            if (arr[j] < pivot) {
                i++
                qSwapHelper(arr, i, j)
            }
        }
        qSwapHelper(arr, i + 1, high)
        return (i + 1)
    }

All of these subroutines were incorporated into a single Application class:
class QuickSort : Application() {

    private val mainAPane = Pane()
    private var array = IntArray(20) { Random.nextInt(0, 100) }
    private val elements = FXCollections.observableArrayList<ElementModel>()
    private val labelWidth = 25.0

    override fun start(stage: Stage) {
        stage.scene = Scene(createContent(), 600.0, 300.0).apply {
            addWidgetStyles()
            QuickSort::class.java.getResource("quicksort.css")?.toString()?.let { stylesheets += it }
        }
        stage.show()
    }
    .
    .
    .
}

fun main() = Application.launch(QuickSort::class.java)

and the CSS is this:
.element-label {
  -fx-border-width : 2px;
  -fx-border-color : black;
  -fx-alignment: center;
}

This is complete code, and will run.
The result is almost Reactive.  The quicksort logic code is impacted by the need to pause while the transactions are taking place.  This could be eliminated by having the quicksort logic generate a series of swap coordinates that are passed back to the layout.  The layout code would then be responsible for executing each swap in order with the transitions.  That is, however, well beyond the scope of the question.
This approach does show, however, that the layout can be static while behaving dynamically simply by manipulating the various Properties of the layout Nodes.
It's also great fun to watch.
